Is the convolution with a Gaussian kernel injective?
I am a beginner in the theoretical aspects of kernels. From some tutorials I find that the Fourier transform of a Gaussian kernel is another Gaussian, which is non-zero everywhere in the frequency domain. This property makes the Gaussian kernel non-degenerate. One can easily conclude that the convolution between the Gaussian kernel and a function is injective from this property.
However, in practice, we are often dealing with bounded domains, where the Fourier transform cannot be applied. In these cases, is this convolution still injective?
Specifically, let $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ be two possibly different bounded domains in $\mathbb{R}^d$.
Denote $f_1\in W^{s,p}(\Omega_1;\mathbb{R})$, $k(x-y)$ the Gaussian kernel, and $f_2(x) = \int_{\Omega_1} k(x-y) f_1(y) \, dy$ for $x \in \Omega_2$. Is this integral operator injective?
I followed the general approach by assume $f_2=0$, $f_1\neq 0$, and look for some contradictions. I tried to extend $f_1$ to the entire $\mathbb{R}^d$, but it does not work well because $f_2$ is not defined on the entire $\mathbb{R}^d$ either.

Do we have $\int_{\Omega_1}|f_1(x)|dx<\infty$ in your hypothesis?

Hi @LetacGérard, thank you for this question. I have modified the question assuming $f_1\in\ W^{k,p}(\Omega_1;\mathbb{R})$ instead of being continuous, with $p\geq 1$ and not necessarily equals to $1$. Therefore I do not have $\int_{\Omega_1}|f_1(x)|dx<\infty$. Does this hypothesis matter for the injectivity?
